# drawing a random number from a histogram

Tags: python, random, plot, numbers, histogram

I have some troubles to draw a random number from a histogram.

If I use the histogram to represent a probability distribution function, how can I efficiently generate 70128 random numbers between 0 and 1 from that distribution and afterwards plot them? I also want the random numbers in a list, then i can work with them later on.

My code for the histogram looks like this:

```
`N = EU_Nodes(load_filename = "linear_gamma=1_B=0_A=0.7.npz")

def close(a,b):
    return ((a < (b*1.00001 + 1e-6)) and (a > (b* 0.99999 - 1e-6))) or (a==b)

def non_zeros(s):
    v=[]
    for w in s:
        if not close(w,0):
            v.append(w)
    return v

x0=-3
x1=3
b=np.arange(x0,x1,(x1-x0)/250.)

u=np.array(N[15].mismatch, dtype=np.float)
uu=np.array(sum(N[15].load)/70128, dtype=np.float)
uv=u/uu

plt.plot(b[0:-1], plt.hist(non_zeros(-uv), bins=b, normed=1, visible=0)[0], color = "k")`
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a class that takes a histogram and the values that correspond to each histogram bucket. The `random` method returns a random value with the same distribution as the histogram.

```
import bisect
import random

def accumulate(iterable):
    ''' Produce an accumulated total of the input; adapted from Python 3 itertools.accumulate
    '''
    it = iter(iterable)
    total = next(it)
    yield total
    for element in it:
        total += element
        yield total

class distrib:
    def __init__(self, hist, values):
        total = sum(hist)
        self.ranges = [accumulate(x/total for x in hist)]
        self.ranges[-1] = 1.0  # insure against roundoff error
        self.values = values
    def random(self):
        i = bisect.bisect_left(self.ranges, random.random())
        return self.values[i]
```

Comment: Okay, but how can i plot a new histogram based on these new random values?

Comment: @SmailKozarcanin put them in a list and plot them the same way you did with your original values.

Comment: I am not sure of that I understand the code, that's why I'm not sure of how to put the new values in a list.